# Concerns using Shared Memory with CreateFileMapping and MapViewofFile

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, shared-memory, memory-mapping

I have 2 questions concerns about using shared memory. I'm using CreateFileMapping to create a shared memory area between two processes.

1) I understand that I need to call CloseHandle on every handle returned from a CreateFileMapping or OpenFileMapping call in order to release the memory. My question is, do all handles get closed appropriately and mem deallocated by Windows XP/7 if the programs using the shared memory exit without calling CloseHandle? IE - is there a possibility of a mem leak after all processes using the mem have been closed?

2) I use MapViewofFile to get a pointer to the mem. In 1 instance I've assumed that the shared memory will always exist in the context of a method. So I've saved the return value of MapViewOfFile as a pointer and closed the handle to the mem and am just using the pointer to the shared mem (but still locking access to it). Is this safe, or should I call MapViewOfFile every time I access the shared mem?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Yes, all handles are closed when a process terminates, no matter if it dies or finishes nicely. No leaks here.

2) As long as you don't call `UnmapViewOfFile`, the memory will still be accesible to the process, even if the handle has been closed:

> Although an application may close the file handle used to create a file mapping object, the system holds the corresponding file open until the last view of the file is unmapped